# How to avoid changing the BLOB size?

Tags: javascript

I request some data via `XMLHttpRequest`. 
When i try to save the result as file I've got changed size of file, and the file becomes unreadable.

```
args.response.length 
//9214
new Blob([args.response], {type: args.mime})
//Blob {size: 12252, type: "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8"}
```

How could i avoid this re-encoding and save the file as it comes in response?

Comment: What is `args.response`? What is `args.responseType`? It already should be a blob, so that you don't have to change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` returns one of several types of data. DOMString, ArrayBuffer, Blob, Document, JSON, Text, and browser specific types. You can see them all here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response

More than likely the type is something like a String which has a length that is shorter (due to 2 byte characters and such) than the byte representation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You gave me a hint!

Answer (score 2):

After the answer of PaulBGD i have found the solution. 
The `XMLHttpRequest` returned me the empty `responseType` that was treated as `DOMString`. I just added

`xhr.responseType = 'blob';`

after the request open and it works great.